# ¿Cómo puedo ejecutar un store procedure con parametro de salida?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, oracle-sqldeveloper

quisiera saber como declaro un parámetro de salida para mi store procedure ya que los demás parámetros están  declarados ya solo me falta saber como declarar el valor **C1** que es un sys_refcursor en oracle y que valor deberia ir para que funcione. Agradezco de antemano su ayuda.

store procedure oracle sqlDeveloper

```
create or replace procedure HORAS_SIGERI
  (c1 out sys_refcursor, CODIGO_PROY VARCHAR , FECHA_INICIO_VAL DATE,FECHA_FIN_VAL DATE)
  as
  begin
  open c1 for  SELECT
        rh.id_colaborador,
        rh.nombre_colaborador,
        rh.id_unidad_organizativa,
        rh.id_proyecto,
        rh.descripcion_proyecto,
        rh.tipo_actividad,
        rh.fecha,
        rh.horas_imputadas
    FROM
        view_horas_sigeri rh
    WHERE rh.id_unidad_organizativa =CODIGO_PROY AND rh.fecha BETWEEN fecha_inicio_val AND fecha_fin_val 
    order by 1,7; 
  end;
variable c1  refcursor;
execute HORAS_SIGERI(:C1,'103569','01/07/19','31/07/19');
print c1;
```

Metodo creado para recibir el store procedure tienes las propiedades correspondientes para la creación.

```
public static void CreateCommand(string Source, CommandType CommandType)
        {
            command.CommandText = Source;
            command.CommandType = CommandType;
            command.CommandTimeout = 10;
            command.Connection = cn;
            command.Connection.Open();
        }
```

//Ejecución del método

```
public List<HorasSigeri> GetAllRegistros(string idProyecto,string fechaDesde, string fechaHasta)
    {

    List<HorasSigeri> lsthoras = new List<HorasSigeri>();
    HorasSigeri objHoras;
    idProyecto = "103569";
    try
    {
        OracleConectionBd.OpenConection();
        /*OracleConectionBd.CreateCommand("SELECT ID_COLABORADOR,NOMBRE_COLABORADOR,ID_UNIDAD_ORGANIZATIVA," +
           " ID_PROYECTO, DESCRIPCION_PROYECTO, TIPO_ACTIVIDAD," +
            "FECHA, HORAS_IMPUTADAS FROM VIEW_HORAS_SIGERI WHERE ID_UNIDAD_ORGANIZATIVA IN('103569') AND FECHA  " +
          "  BETWEEN to_date('" + fechaDesde + "','DD/MM/YYYY') AND to_date('" + fechaHasta + "','DD/MM/YYYY') ", CommandType.Text);*/
        OracleConectionBd.CreateCommand("HORAS_SIGERI(:C1'" + idProyecto + "','" + DateTime.Parse(fechaDesde) + "','" + DateTime.Parse(fechaHasta) + "')", CommandType.StoredProcedure);


        using (IDataReader oReader = OracleConectionBd.GetDataReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
        {

                while (oReader.Read())
                {
                    objHoras = new HorasSigeri();
                    objHoras.ID_COLABORADOR = Convert.ToString(oReader["ID_COLABORADOR"]);
                    objHoras.NOMBRE_COLABORADOR = Convert.ToString(oReader["NOMBRE_COLABORADOR"]);
                    objHoras.ID_UNIDAD_ORGANIZATIVA = Convert.ToString(oReader["ID_UNIDAD_ORGANIZATIVA"]);
                    objHoras.ID_PROYECTO = Convert.ToDecimal(oReader["ID_PROYECTO"]);
                    objHoras.DESCRIPCION_PROYECTO = Convert.ToString(oReader["DESCRIPCION_PROYECTO"]);
                    objHoras.TIPO_ACTIVIDAD = Convert.ToString(oReader["TIPO_ACTIVIDAD"]);
                    objHoras.FECHA = Convert.ToDateTime(oReader["FECHA"]);
                    objHoras.HORAS_IMPUTADAS = Convert.ToDecimal(oReader["HORAS_IMPUTADAS"]);

                    lsthoras.Add(objHoras);
                }


            oReader.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        OracleConectionBd.CloseConection();
    }
    return lsthoras;
}
```

Al ejecutar el metodo me devuelve el siguiente error **not all variables bound** en el visual studio

Comment: Debes de cambiar el modo en el que llamas a tu sp, por algo como .Parameters.Add("c1", OracleDbType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

Comment: Es un código ya hecho la cual se debe usar eso.

Comment: No te entendi muy bien

Comment: no se que haces con el `OracleConectionBd.CreateCommand()` pero unir los valores en un string esta MAL, tienes que usar parametro con el command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El parametro se define usando

```
command.Parameters.Add("c1", null, OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output);
```

o tambien

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("c1", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

[Return sys_refcursor of the oracle to c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32953374/return-sys-refcursor-of-the-oracle-to-c-sharp)

[C# - Oracle: Procedimientos Almacenados](http://pabletoreto.blogspot.com/2015/01/c-oracle-pl-sql-12.html)

analiza como utiliza

```
 objSelectCmd.Parameters.Add("id_", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 20).Value = id;
 objSelectCmd.Parameters.Add("nombre_", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 20).Value = nombre;
 objSelectCmd.Parameters.Add("cargo_", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 20).Value = cargo;
```

para asignar los valores al procedure

NUNCA se concatenan en un string